# Add surrounding div container with css class to above div container's id with jQuery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Would be very easy to embed the missing div container in the html ...if I only could add it. I'm limited to "jimdo's" head area to manipulate classes and id's from there. Code is already written but it seems to me the only way that works is to do that with jQuery or Javascript?

So, I have this code here:

```html
<div id="1" class="2">

<div class="3"></div>

<div class="4"></div>

<div class="5"></div>
</div>
```

And the missing div container in the html `<div class="margin">` needs to be under the first div container from top `<div id="1" class="2">` added by its id `#1` and then surrounds the rest code below into the new added `<div class="margin">`

Like this:

```html
<div id="1" class="2">

<div class="margin">

<div class="3"></div>

<div class="4"></div>

<div class="5"></div>
</div>
</div>
```

Is it possible to add it like that with jQuery or javascript? If so, maybe someone could show me how to implement this?

Answer (score 0):

You can try [`$.before()`](https://api.jquery.com/before/) to append the `<div class="margin">` before the target:

```js
const $container = $("#cc-m-7032876518");
$container.before(`<div class="margin">`);
```

Comment: Made a code mistake. Post is updated. Can you please read it again and edit your code to that?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this with jquery.

```js
let children = $("#1").clone().children().wrap( "<div class='margin'></div>" );
$("#1").empty().append(children);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="1" class="2">

<div class="margin">

<div class="3"></div>

<div class="4"></div>

<div class="5"></div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you very much but unfortunately not working for me with jimdo. Maybe better with javascript?

Comment: ok implemented the same solution using javascript. Try the solution here. https://jsfiddle.net/sahanHaz/shpLotaz/51/

Comment: Hi, thanks @SahanSira but this won't work either :( After my experience all of the codes worked in jimdo starts with `$(document).ready(function() {`. Sorry but in look I really can't say the differences between java, javascript and jquery.

Comment: Its fine. Add te javascript code inside the $(document).ready(function() {